# Visual Studio 2015 + Xamarin > Select a valid device before running the application

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I have the latest alpha builds of xamarin recently uninstalled everything on both mac and pc (windows 8).  I get the error "select a valid device" when trying to run the ios sample application.

I have set the platform to iphonesimulator, i am connected to the mac.  The following is the log when building

Starting Agent IDB 4.0.0.1566...
Connected to the MacBook-Pro.local (192.168.1.120) with Limited support.
An error occured starting the IDB 4.0.0.1566 agent: The operation has timed out.

Starting Agent Build 4.0.0.1566...
Agent IDB 4.0.0.1566 is running
Agent Build 4.0.0.1566 is running
Starting Agent Designer 4.0.0.1566...
An error occured starting the Designer 4.0.0.1566 agent: The operation has timed out.

The Xamarin Mac Agent could not be fully started. Agents not started: Designer 4.0.0.1566. Please check the logs for more details.
Agent Designer 4.0.0.1566 is running
Connected to the Mac MacBook-Pro.local (192.168.1.120) with Full support.

The application works fine when run on the mac and the simulator works fine.  I have the latest xcode and can run an application from xcode as well.

Properties of IOS project  - i do see this error "failed to obtain profile information from the build server.  Please, check the connectivity with the mac build host' > i have done this an everything looks connected.

Ideas??

Comment: Do you have the alpha version installed now? Is there a specific reason you have? If not, I think you should stick with the stable builds. Those will probably work.

Comment: Open Xcode on the Mac build-host, and make sure you accept any pop-up prompts. When Xcode is first installed and/or updated, it requires you to open the Xcode app and accept the user agreements before you can build your first app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have development certificate installed on your MAC. Also your device should be provisioned for development. For details [check here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/)

Answer (score 4):

**For those that end up here in April 2018, there is currently an issue with Xamarin and xcode 9.3.**

ensure that your mac has xcode 9.2 (I also had to completely remove 9.3), which you can download from the apple developers site.

- un-install xcode 9.3 on mac
- install xcode 9.2 on mac
- restart mac
- in visual studio - forget mac connection, re-connect when mac back up.

update*

Apparently this is fixed in Visual studio update 15.6.5, although not personally test myself yet

Comment: I can say that I tested the latest version and it is now working again with xcode 9.3, with both VS15 and 17. Was having this problem last week and took the time to update both my Mac and the PC with the latest versions and all started working again

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your root issue is that the Xamarin Mac Agent isn't connecting. Without this connection, most all iOS development cannot be run.

I can suggest two things.
1) reboot the mac - sometimes when you uninstall/reinstall or something goes wrong processes can be orphaned which cause problems, simple reboot might resolve your problem.

2) try the troubleshooting steps here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/

Answer (score 1):

XCode 9.3 was recently released by Apple, that version is not compatible with the current Xamarin SDK.  Xamarin has released updates to their SDK that fix the issue on both the Mac and PC.  You can get them here:  https://releases.xamarin.com/preview-xcode-9-3-beta-2-ios-11-3-macos-10-13-4-support-preview-2/